# Alternative to database.yml configuration file

Tags: php, database, symfony1, yaml, configure

I would like to know if it's possible in symfony 1.4 to set the db connection password (and username) somewhere else, or if it's possible to encrypt this data somehow.

The client who asked for it said it results unsecure, so i'm looking for an alternative way to do this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use php in yml files:

```
all:
  doctrine:
    class: sfDoctrineDatabase
    param:
      dsn: '<?php echo DSN_CONSTANT ?>'
      username: '<?php echo $_ENV['DB_USERNAME'] ?>'
      password: '<?php echo $_ENV['DB_PASSWORD'] ?>'
```

EDIT:

The above way will store credentials on filesystem, in php files. If you want to prevent this, change the `class` to your own, extend it, and retrieve the credentials any other way you want, eg, enviroment variables:

```
class MyDoctrineDatabase extends sfDoctrineDatabase {
  public function initialize($parameters = array())
  {
    $parameters['dsn'] = $_ENV['DSN'];
    $parameters['username'] = $_ENV['DB_USERNAME'];
    $parameters['password'] = $_ENV['DB_PASSWORD'];
    return parent::initialize($parameters);
  }
}
```

Comment: I think that could be a really good possibility. Thank you! 
That was fast!

Comment: If I use my own DoctrineDatabase, in this case will i have to set also the parameters in the yaml file? Or it won't be neccessary? I immagine something like this in the yaml:
all:
  doctrine:
    class: MyDoctrineDatabase

Comment: Yes, exactly that's what I meant by 'change the class to your own'.